# How to make multiple page webpack build with 3 entry point without repetion of config code?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-4, commonschunkplugin

I need to create a multiple web app with 10 pages and 3 entry point. Do I should create 11 *HtmlWebpackPlugin* and write chunks what I want to use in every HTML files.

**My file tree**:

[image: My file tree]

In result, I want to see something like that:

[image: code]

The version of webpack - 4.5.0

I am also interested in how to work with *webpack-dev-server* and *python3(tornado)* server in this situation?

I understand that not hard to do, but actually(wp 4.5.0) information I can`t find, and documentation is hard to read for men who only begins to work with webpack.